# How to automatically rebuild a precompiled header using qmake when its dependencies change?

Tags: clang, qmake, precompiled-headers

I'm using qmake's `PRECOMPILED_HEADER` variable to generate a precompiled header.

If one of the precompiled header's included headers changes, the precompiled header isn't rebuilt — instead, when clang tries to use the precompiled header, it fails with `fatal error: file '...' has been modified since the precompiled header was built`.

How can I tell qmake to automatically recompile the precompiled header when its dependencies change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I had `CONFIG -= depend_includepath` enabled, and I had added the precompiled header's headers to `INCLUDEPATH` but hadn't also added them to `DEPENDPATH`.

Answer (score 0):

Edit prefix header anyhow. E.g if your precompiled header created from `stdafx.h`, open `stdafx.h` and type something, than delete it, save file and launch build again.

Comment: Thanks.  I know how to resolve the problem when it occurs (touch the precompiled header input file, or delete the precompiled header output file), but what I'm looking for is a way to tell qmake to automatically do that for me when a dependency changes.  (I just modified the question to clarify that.)

Comment: Report bug to Qt bugtracker (component qt-base).